# Can't drag and drop images from Firefox 10/11 to Finder in Mac OS X 10.6.8

Tags: macos, mac, firefox

I had Firefox 10.0.2 and now Firefox 11.0 on Mac OS X 10.6.8. For both versions I lost the ability to drag and drop images on a webpage onto the desktop/Finder window, etc. Now I have to right click on each image and save them as files on my computer.

BTW, when I try to drag an image from a webpage, I can see it being dragged out of the Firefox window. But when I drop it on the Desktop, or a folder, it doesn't move there...

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: you can always just copy/paste if you want it to go to a document and cut out some of the steps, but i'm not sure thats what your looking for...

Comment: Unfortunately no. I am looking for a way to directly drag an image in a webpage into a Finder window or the Desktop, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Worked for me just now, FF 11.0, MacOS 10.6.8, dragging to my desktop.  Will it work in a new profile?  In a new user-account?